# Definition for $\pi$-number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

From the book An Introduction to the Theory of Groups by Rotman,

> If $\pi$ is a set of primes, then a **$\pi$-number** is an integer $n$ all of whose prime factors lie in $\pi$; the complement of $\pi$ is denoted by $\pi'$, and so a **$\pi'$-number** is an integer $n$ none of whose prime factors lie in $\pi$.

For example, $\pi=\{3,5\}$. Is $3$ a $\pi$-number? or a $\pi$-number must be product of positive power of each primes in $\pi$?

I copy down the next two definitions stated in the book.

> If $G$ is a finite group, then a **Hall subgroup** $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup whose order and index are relatively prime.

Next one

> If $\pi$ is a set of primes, then a group $G$ is a **$\pi$-group** if the order of each its elements is a $\pi$-number.

Note that the definition for a Hall $\pi$-subgroup is not given in the book.

The writer wanted to prove that Hall $\pi$-subgroup(with $|\pi|\geq2$) of a group need not exist.

> For example, let $G=A_5$ and $\pi=\{3,5\}$; since $|A_5|=60$, a Hall $\pi$-subgroup would have index $4$ and order $15$.

My question is can that Hall $\pi$-subgroup be of order $3$ or $5$? since it follows the definition of $\pi$-group and also its index will be $20$ and $12$ respectively which are also relatively prime to its order.

Comment: $3$ is indeed a $\pi$-number for that choice of $\pi$.

Comment: 3 would count by that definition. All of the prime factors of 3 are in the set, sure there are others, but it doesn't say it has to have them all.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue you have is in your edit. $a$ being a $p'$-number just means it is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: So what exactly is your question with regards to the new definition that you'e just added? It sure doesn't seem to have any impact on the original question (the answer to which, as others have already mentioned, is of $3$ indeed being a $\pi$-number).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In my edit just now, I want to ask whether a subgroup of order dividing $a$ can be a $p$-complement. But i just realize the $p$-complement defined is different from $p'$-number.

Comment: Ahh, so being a Hall $\pi$-subgroupgroup is stronger than being a $\pi$-subgroup (much stronger). It means being a $\pi$-subgroup and having order and index be coprime (satisfying the latter is what is called a Hall subgroup in general, and specifying it to be a Hall $\pi$-subgroup just means mentioning which primes divide the order).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I also checked its definition from wikipedia. So does it mean that the definition of Hall $\pi$-subgroup can't be assumed by combining both definition of Hall subgroup and $\pi$-group?

Comment: Yes, being a Hall $\pi$-subgroup is the same as being both a Hall subgroup and a $\pi$-group (note that being a $\pi$-group is something that does not rely on any overlying group, but being a Hall subgroup does depend on this).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But from what i have found in wikipedia its index cannot be divisible by any primes in $\pi$ right? This criterion is not found from the definition of $\pi$-group or Hall subgroup.

Comment: Hmm, now I am becoming unsure if people would call a Sylow subgroup a Hall $\pi$-subgroup for $|\pi| \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, Rotman doesn't actually define a Hall $\pi$-subgroup but (according to his definitions) it is not the same asa  Hall subgroup that is also a $\pi$-group.

The standard definition of a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of a group $H$ is a subgroup such that all primes dividing $H$ lie in $\pi$ (i.e. $H$ is a $\pi$-group) and also all primes that divide $|G:H|$ lie in $\pi'$.

So a Hall $\{3,5\}$-subgroup of a group of order $60$ would have order $15$, and $A_5$ has no such subgroup.